# How can the ref keyword be avoided when pattern matching in a function taking &self or &mut self?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

The Rust book [calls the `ref` keyword "legacy"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#legacy-patterns-ref-and-ref-mut). As I want to follow the implicit advice to avoid `ref`, how can I do it in the following toy example? You can find the code also on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dddf5b646d2502c8fc0030ec2f50c537).

```
struct OwnBox(i32);

impl OwnBox {
    fn ref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32 {
        match *self {
            OwnBox(ref mut i) => i,
        }

        // This doesn't work. -- Even not, if the signature of the signature of the function is
        // adapted to take an explcit lifetime 'a and use it here like `&'a mut i`.
        // match *self {
        //     OwnBox(mut i) => &mut i,
        // }

        // This doesn't work
        // match self {
        //     &mut OwnBox(mut i) => &mut i,
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the book is wrong to call these "legacy"; as it points out, you still need them in some situations, and sometimes it can be clearer to use `ref`. So, definitely be aware of "pattern ergonomics" and how it works, but also I don't think you should go out of your way to avoid `ref` and `ref mut`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `self` is of type `&mut Self`, it is enough to match against itself, while omitting `ref` entirely. Either dereferencing it with `*self` or adding `&` to the match arm would cause an unwanted move.

```
fn ref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32 {
    match self {
        OwnBox(i) => i,
    }
}
```

For newtypes such as this one however, `&mut self.0` would have been enough.

This is thanks to [RFC 2005 — Match Ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html).