# Why does Option<i32> lose mutability inside matched pattern?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, mutability

I'd like to change `my_id`, only if present, to another value:

```
fn read(id: &mut i32) {
    *id = 42;
}

struct S {
    my_id: Option<i32>,
}

impl S {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        match self.my_id {
            Some(mut id) => read(&mut id),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S { my_id: 0.into() };

    s.run();

    println!("{:?}", s.my_id);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7d46098ab91cacc4363a3f2ff2aa15e)

This code prints `Some(0)`, which means the substitution failed, but I don't understand why. Am I losing the mutability because of pattern matching?

Answer (score 7):

[Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62517851/2766908) and [mcarton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62517936/2766908) gave great explanations how your `i32` is being copied instead of referenced in the pattern match.

I'd like to add that the `ref` keyword exists specifically to handle cases like this, where you want a reference and not a copy inside a pattern match:

```rust
fn read(id: &mut i32) {
    *id = 42;
}

struct S {
    my_id: Option<i32>,
}

impl S {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        match self.my_id {
            // `ref` keyword added here
            Some(ref mut id) => read(id),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S { my_id: 0.into() };
    s.run();
    println!("{:?}", s.my_id); // prints "Some(42)"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1f68b51fc6c29c8ceed44ec5d884da2)

See also:

- [Was Rust's ref keyword avoidable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58292554/2766908)
- [How can the ref keyword be avoided when pattern matching in a function taking &self or &mut self?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130932/2766908)
- [Why is `ref` used instead of an asterisk in pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58184472/2766908)

Answer (score 5):

The problem becomes obvious when you replace the type of `my_id` by a non-Copy type:

```rust
fn read(_: &mut String) {}

struct S {
    my_id: Option<String>,
}

impl S {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        match self.my_id {
            Some(mut id) => read(&mut id),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.my_id.0` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:9:15
   |
9  |         match self.my_id {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&self.my_id`
10 |             Some(mut id) => read(&mut id),
   |                  ------
   |                  |
   |                  data moved here
   |                  move occurs because `id` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Indeed `Some(mut id)` does not match by reference: You've just made a copy of the field. What you really wanted was to match on `&mut self.my_id`, which doesn't require `mut` in the pattern:

```
match &mut self.my_id {
    Some(id) => read(id),
    _ => (),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. By using `Some(mut id)`, you are stating that `id` should be an `i32`. Because `i32` implements `Copy`, a mutable *copy* of the value stored in `self` is made, then modified by `read`. At no point is the value inside `self` modified.

The direct fix is to take a reference:

```
match &mut self.my_id {
    Some(id) => read(id),
    _ => (),
}
```

This is more idiomatically written with an `if let`:

```rust
if let Some(id) = &mut self.my_id {
    read(id);
}
```